# Bare bones necessary to run pipeline on snakemake?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, snakemake

I have to perform imputation of genetic information, but scripts and files are located on different locations. There are some parallel jobs for could (cluster) involved as well. Too much of a manual running-waiting is necessary to get job done.

In order to streamline the mess, i want to put these bash scripts in Snakemake pipeline. The expected outcome would be a Snakefile with rules consisting only of shell scripts as input/output files are already specified.

For that i basically have to run this simple example:

Let's say we have input called test.txt containting list:

```
13 234 34 4
```

And bash script for ordering, called test.sh:

```
sort -n test.txt > test1.txt
```

In order to run this script through Snakemake, i made Snakefile:

```
rule sort:
    shell:
            "path/to/test.sh"
```

When i run it using command

```
snakemake Snakefile
```

i get following error:

```
/usr/bin/bash: path/to/test.sh: Permission denied
```

Could you guys point me on why such syntax would not work with snakemake?

Comment: Your question is better suited to [Ask Ubuntu](http://askubuntu.com/tour). This site is for programming related questions.

Comment: Is `test.sh` actually executable (valid shebang, `chmod +x`, etc)? Are all the directories upstream of it `+x` by the user running the build tool? Is the file itself `+r` for that same account? Show enough of your existing investigation that we can have a reasonable idea of where to start.

Comment: Cyrus, issue wraps around correct syntax of snakemake (or python, as it's build on it). Snakemake is widely discussed on stack overflow.

Comment: If you have problems with code, you first have to extract a [mcve] and post that alongside your question. Further, don't blindly accept the suggested tags, study their description and then make an informed decision. That said, as a new user, take the [tour] and read [ask] if you haven't already.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy , i have no problem running analogous examples when additional syntax is added, like "rule all:", input and output

Comment: @juststuck, ...that really doesn't answer my questions. Maybe it would help, if you *showed* those specific working examples, doubly so if they worked *with the same `test.sh`*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So the problem is being hinted at in the comments.

There are two likely possible problems. One is that the path to the file is incorrect, the other is that the path is correct, but the file is 'not executable'.

If the file is not executable, then it has little to do with snakemake. The solution is easy though. Just use the command proposed by @CharlesDuffy:

```
chmod +x path/to/test.sh
```